# PHP: Show user custom error, inside body

Tags: php, exception, backtrace

I am wanting to throw custom errors in many places in some interfaces that I am building.  Just using an echo inside my function places that echoed code above the  tag in my page.  So, I built a custom function to handle errors and give me a backtrace, but again, it prints above the  in my page.

Here is the function I am using:

```
function error($msg) {
    trigger_error($msg, E_USER_WARNING);
    echo '<pre>';
    debug_print_backtrace();
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

How can I get my errors to print inside the  tags of my page?

Or, is there a better method to do this?

Comment: Are you calling `error` before you've started outputting the body? If so, the solution is to delay printing errors.

Comment: Yes I am.  How would I delay printing errors?  Ideally, I would love to have a <div id="errors">Errors here</div> that would always be put in the body if there is an error.

Comment: Delaying error printing will either be unclean (using a global variable (yuck) to indicate that the body has started) or somewhat complex. In the complex case, you could build a document (e.g. using http://php.net/DOM), which will let you insert nodes at any point during processing, until you're ready to output the doc. You might be able to create a hybrid solution, delaying printing whenever the target ancestor node has yet to start printing, printing immediately when the ancestor's open tag (but not close tag) has been printed, and do something else when the ancestor has been closed.

Comment: konforce's answer is an example of the hybrid solution, where errors are ignored once the target ancestor has been printed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How would I delay printing errors? Ideally, I would love to have a Errors here that would always be put in the body if there is an error

I'm not sure if I completely follow what you are doing, but maybe this is it?

```
<?php
class ErrorHandler
{
  static private $errors = null;

  static function report( ... /* see set_error_handler() for params */ )
  {       
    self::$errors .= "...";
    return true;
  }

  static function getErrors()
  {
     return self::$errors;
  }
}

set_error_handler(array('ErrorHandler', 'report'));

// ...

echo "<div>".ErrorHandler::getErrors()."</div>
?>
```

Comment: The main changes I'd make is to turn `ErrorHandler::$errors` into an array and combine the items using `implode`, which more readily allows for additional processing of error messages. Also, consider using a list element rather than a div.

Answer (score 1):

If your server runs php5, you shall use the [exceptions handler](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php).
It's exactly what you need and once you get how it works, they're really useful.

[Here's a nice tutorial on how to use them ;)](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/PHP-Exceptions.html)